# Copying data from cells in column A to C on Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

To copy data from column A to column C

If Cell A empty, to take data from column B

If both cell empty mention Nil

Google Sheetlink - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19M0DlaRY_JgcgyyG2GpGhuEpdqMiDX-y2YoTA0TIakQ/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

I have tried

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2="",A2,B2))
```

The results are incorrect

Comment: [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files. Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: I have tried =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2="",A2,B2)), the results are incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MAP` to get each value, `IFS` to check if empty and return appropriate values:

```
=MAP(A2:A15,B2:B15,LAMBDA(a,b,IFS(a<>"",a,b<>"",b,true,"Nil")))
```

Advantage: You only need to enter the range once.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A10="", IF(B2:B10="", "Nil", B2:B10), A2:A10))
```

[image]

advantage: it's simple